# Google analytics API - how to create new account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Okay, some heads-ups as I feel I'm an idiot and missing some simple stuff. As far as I understand Google Analytics works with a 3 tiers system: account -> property -> view. and I should be able to manage these 3 levels via the google analytics management api.

For some context as to why I encounter this issue. I am making a CMS in which I want to register a new google analytics account per user, and a property per website this user has. (implementation and usage of views out of scope for now, I will implement those on a later date). To achieve all of this I started following Google's documentation on the Google Analytics Management API (according to Google this is what manages accounts, properties and views). Therefor I have made a service-user-account which should have enough permissions to manage GA-accounts.

However I can't seem to be able to create a new account via the API. Am I missing something obvious? Is it not possible at all this way? If so, how then? Because my goal is to have GA on every website, without the user having to config anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it. The management API only allows for the list operation on accounts: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management#account_summaries

The only solution would be to use the Provisioning API. It can be used to create new Google Analytics accounts and enable Google Analytics for your customers at scale: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/

Anyway, the Provisioning API is currently available by invitation only.

Comment: any clue as for a work around, so that I can still achieve my goal? or is this truly a lost cause?

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, will try to obtain an invite I guess :P